# Fresh install of OS+Firefox and now there's a persistent notification

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, firefox-for-android

I just reformatted and reinstalled things on my phone to fix some issues.  I installed Firefox from apkmirror and now there's a mostly persistent notification that shows up when I go to certain sites (The Guardian and AJC were two that it popped up on).  There was a mention of a playback queue wen I was experimenting with closing the notification, so it seems video related.

I used Android 6's notification manager to block all popups, which is the nuclear option.  I can't think of a reason why I'd want a notification from Firefox, but I could not find a way within Firefox to disable the notification.

**What is this new anti-feature called, and how are you supposed to disable it within Firefox?**

OctOS M (Android 6), Firefox firefox_67.0-2015628937_minAPI16(armeabi-v7a)(nodpi)

Comment: I found the same topic on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9iunww/persistent_notification_on_websites_that_have/) and seems it's called "Media playback" notification, but the solution might only work for Android 8 Oreo. I'm not really sure if [per-site notification](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-notifications-firefox-android) is related.

Comment: Why is there this idea that it's OK to bombard the user with notifications and popups and toolbars until they have to buy a new device?  It seems like it's a never ending battle...